# Compare two dataframe columns of sentence strings and create new values for a third frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Here, I have two dataframe columns. A and B. For each row[i], All of B is contained in A, Now i am trying to test for B in A, and return 1 for all the words in the matching phrase, and 0 for all other words in A outside phrase B, thus creating a new dataframe of 0's and 1's.

```
    Why would it be competitive, so it's wond...        if the teabaggers hadn't ousted Sen
    Had he refused to attempt something so partisa...   Had he refused to attempt something so partisa...
    "This study would then have to be conducted an...   This study would then have to be conducted and
```

Expected dataframe.

```
['0', '0', '0', '0' , '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'........]
```

I have primarily tried two methods, but in the first method which i got here on stackoverflow, it was testing for individual words in B and not the entire phrase of column B,  so that i would have results like this

```
['0', '1', '0', '0' , '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', ........]
```

where a value in B such as "is" or "and" was always liable to occur outside the phrase and return a bad result.

I also tried regular expressions, which worked perfectly for a single instance, but i was not able to apply it over the dataframes with good results. It was sort of a ratchet job and it would return endless rows of 1's or run out of memory.

```
rx = '({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(el)for el in B))
     # Generator to yield replaced sentences, rep_lace is a column of 1's for each word in B
it = (re.sub(rx, rep_lace, sentence)for sentence in A)
     # Build list of paired new sentences and old to filter out where not the same
results.append([new_sentence for old_sentence, new_sentence in zip(A, it) if old_sentence != new_sentence])
nw_results = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in results])
ew_results= nw_results.split(" ")
new_results = ['0' if i is not '1' else i for i in ew_results]
labels =([int(e) for e in new_results])
```

I hope that i gave a clear enough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand fully what you mean about 'is' and 'and' and why they generate errors. But in general, if you're trying to construct column C based on values in columns A and B, the best way to approach this is with a lambda function.

```
def word_match(col_1, col_2):
    # Gather all words in column B to check column A against
    targets = set(col_2.split())
    # For each word in A, if it's in B then 1, else 0
    output = [1 if x in targets else 0 for x in col_1.split()]
    return output

# Create new column, C, whose value on each row is word_match(A, B) on each row
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: word_match(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What i mean is this, given an instance of B e.g ['there are many happy people'], and A[there are many happy people who say say that they are happy with the government],  you can observe that the words 'are' and 'happy', occur in phrase B but also occur in A outside the specified phrase. This will lead to it returning 1's outside the desired span of B in A.

Comment: I will post the method i used here. it involved regex though